# ServerSignature in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, centos6

I'm installing apache on CentOS 6.5 and trying to setup some hardening. Part of this process is removing the server signature with the `ServerSignature` directive. Since I'd like this to survive version upgrades and follow other best practices, I'm attempting to make all my setting changes in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory. Here's my `conf.d/defaults.conf` file:

```
ServerTokens Prod

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ServerSignature Off
```

This works great except for the ServerSignature directive. It seems that since it is set in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` by default that it's value cannot be changed. If I comment out that line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` than this directive works fine in my `conf.d/defaults.conf` file. Is this a bug in the apache configuration? All of the other directives I have tried will overwrite defaults. How can I override this value without modifying the line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`?

Comment: "ServerSignature" == "Security by Obscurity" != "Hardening". Also, Apache's configuration is nothing like the mess in CentOS - that's RedHat's own configuration for Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As for the original question** - it might be because the `Include conf.d/*.conf` line comes before `ServerSignature On`. So the latest setting for that name overrides the previews one.

**About proper configuration file management**

It's quite OK to edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. That file will **not** be overwritten by yum/rpm update, instead it will create a `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew` file which the system administrator (you) is supposed to merge with the local configuration manually (most of the time using `vimdiff`).

**About security**
As said by others - hiding server version number won't help you with security - that's especially true for CentOS. By default configuration all httpd exposes about itself is this: `Apache/2.2.15`. That number doesn't change during CentOS 6 lifetime. It was 2.2.15 when 6.0 was released and it will stay the same for the next 6 years while CentOS 6 is still supported. So from that version number the attacked can just guess that you are using the httpd from CentOS 6 repos - that's all.

And if the idea is to hide the fact of using Apache at all (not just the version number), that is almost impossible, all the web servers have some unique characteristics (error documents, header ordering, TCP flags, ...) which are very hard to hide and easy to fingerprint.

Comment: I suppose hardening was a bad choice of words for this context. I understand that removing the signature does not make the server any more secure, but rather just limits the information available. Anyone who wants to know could easily find out, but I would prefer that they had to work for it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that as Chris S pointed out removing the server signature does not really secure a server. If you just want to reduce the amount of information that the server shows, it's better to use the [ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive on your conf.d file.